# Weird results from program that reads number of bytes in an unformatted .wav file?

Tags: c, numbers, byte, wav

First of all, when I run the program, it prints a null space and then AVE when it's supposed to print "WAVE". Secondly, it concatenates "RIFF" (already printed) with " AVE" and then " AVE RIFF" with "fmt" and then "fmt  AVE RIFF" with "data" each time I print the string. It's also giving me different values for BlockAlign. When I use Structs none of this happens, but when I remove the Structs (which I'm supposed to do for this project), it's giving me different results. What's wrong with my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fp;
    unsigned int ChunkSize, SubChunk1Size, SubChunk2Size, RIFFSize, fmtSize, dataSize, SampleRate, ByteRate, BlockAlign;
    unsigned short int AudioFormat, NumChannels, BitsPerSample;
    char ChunkID[4], Format[4], Subchunk1ID[3], Subchunk2ID[4];
    //open file
    fp = fopen("giants.wav", "rb");
    if (!fp) {
        printf("Error: file does not exist.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    //read into
    //RIFF
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fread(ChunkID, 1, 4, fp);
    //ChunkSize
    fseek(fp, 4, SEEK_SET);
    fread(&ChunkSize, 1, 4, fp);
    //WAVE
    fseek(fp, 8, SEEK_SET);
    fread(Format, 1, 4, fp);
    //fmt
    fseek(fp, 12, SEEK_SET);
    fread(Subchunk1ID, 1, 4, fp);
    //Subchunk1Size
    fseek(fp, 16, SEEK_SET);
    fread(&SubChunk1Size, 1, 4, fp);
    //AudioFormat
    fseek(fp, 20, SEEK_SET);
    fread(&AudioFormat, 1, 2, fp);
    //NumChannels
    fseek(fp, 22, SEEK_SET);
    fread(&NumChannels, 1, 2, fp);
    //SampleRate
    fseek(fp, 24, SEEK_SET);
    fread(&SampleRate, 1, 4, fp);
    //ByteRate
    fseek(fp, 28, SEEK_SET);
    fread(&ByteRate, 1, 2, fp);
    //BlockAlign
    fseek(fp, 32, SEEK_SET);
    fread(&BlockAlign, 1, 4, fp);
    //BitsPerSample
    fseek(fp, 34, SEEK_SET);
    fread(&BitsPerSample, 1, 2, fp);
    //data
    fseek(fp, 36, SEEK_SET);
    fread(Subchunk2ID, 1, 4, fp);
    //Size of Subchunk2Size
    fseek(fp, 40, SEEK_SET);
    fread(&SubChunk2Size, 1, 4, fp);
    //close file
    fclose(fp);
    //get sizes
    fmtSize = SubChunk1Size + 8;
    dataSize = SubChunk2Size + 8;
    RIFFSize = ChunkSize + 8 - (fmtSize + dataSize);
    //print chars and sizes
    printf("RIFF Size:     %d\n", RIFFSize);
    printf("fmt Size:      %d\n", fmtSize);
    printf("data Size:     %d\n\n", dataSize);
    printf("ChunkID:       %s\n", ChunkID);
    printf("ChunkSize:     %d\n", ChunkSize);
    printf("Format:        %s\n\n", Format);
    printf("Subchunk1ID:   %s\n", Subchunk1ID);
    printf("Subchunk1Size: %d\n", SubChunk1Size);
    printf("AudioFormat:   %d\n", AudioFormat);
    printf("NumChannels:   %d\n", NumChannels);
    printf("SampleRate:    %d\n", SampleRate);
    printf("ByteRate:      %d\n", ByteRate);
    printf("BlockAlign:    %d\n", BlockAlign);
    printf("BitsPerSample: %d\n\n", BitsPerSample);
    printf("Subchunk2ID:   %s\n", Subchunk2ID);
    printf("Subchunk2Size: %d\n", SubChunk2Size);
    //exit the program
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Here's the output:

RIFF Size:     12

fmt Size:      24

data Size:     2577064

ChunkID:       RIFF

ChunkSize:     2577092

Format:         AVERIFF

Subchunk1ID:   fmt AVERIFF

Subchunk1Size: 16

AudioFormat:   1

NumChannels:   2

SampleRate:    44100

ByteRate:      45328

BlockAlign:    262146

BitsPerSample: 16

Subchunk2ID:   datafmt AVERIFF

Subchunk2Size: 2577056

Comment: This may not be related, but if `chunkId` is 4 bytes, and you want to print it as a string then you need 5 bytes so you can add a 0 terminator...

Comment: Use at least `stdint.h` types in a `struct`, not that bunch of variables with unspecified length. And check endianess for the scalars.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comment, size 5 for each char array. Also, I had some of the sizes incorrect in my fread statements. Corrected and simplified code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fp;
    unsigned int ChunkSize, SubChunk1Size, SubChunk2Size, RIFFSize, fmtSize, dataSize, SampleRate, ByteRate, BlockAlign;
    unsigned short int AudioFormat, NumChannels, BitsPerSample;
    char ChunkID[5], Format[5], Subchunk1ID[5], Subchunk2ID[5];
    ChunkID[4] = '\0';
    Format[4] = '\0';
    Subchunk1ID[4] = '\0';
    Subchunk2ID[4] = '\0';
    fp = fopen("giants.wav", "rb");
    if (!fp) {
        printf("Error: file does not exist.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    fread(ChunkID, 1, 4, fp);
    fread(&ChunkSize, 1, 4, fp);
    fread(Format, 1, 4, fp);
    fread(Subchunk1ID, 1, 4, fp);
    fread(&SubChunk1Size, 1, 4, fp);
    fread(&AudioFormat, 1, 2, fp);
    fread(&NumChannels, 1, 2, fp);
    fread(&SampleRate, 1, 4, fp);
    fread(&ByteRate, 1, 4, fp);
    fread(&BlockAlign, 1, 2, fp);
    fread(&BitsPerSample, 1, 2, fp);
    fread(Subchunk2ID, 1, 4, fp);
    fread(&SubChunk2Size, 1, 4, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    fmtSize = SubChunk1Size + 8;
    dataSize = SubChunk2Size + 8;
    RIFFSize = ChunkSize + 8 - (fmtSize + dataSize);
    printf("RIFF Size:     %d\n", RIFFSize);
    printf("fmt Size:      %d\n", fmtSize);
    printf("data Size:     %d\n\n", dataSize);
    printf("ChunkID:       %s\n", ChunkID);
    printf("ChunkSize:     %d\n", ChunkSize);
    printf("Format:        %s\n\n", Format);
    printf("Subchunk1ID:   %s\n", Subchunk1ID);
    printf("Subchunk1Size: %d\n", SubChunk1Size);
    printf("AudioFormat:   %d\n", AudioFormat);
    printf("NumChannels:   %d\n", NumChannels);
    printf("SampleRate:    %d\n", SampleRate);
    printf("ByteRate:      %d\n", ByteRate);
    printf("BlockAlign:    %d\n", BlockAlign);
    printf("BitsPerSample: %d\n\n", BitsPerSample);
    printf("Subchunk2ID:   %s\n", Subchunk2ID);
    printf("Subchunk2Size: %d\n", SubChunk2Size);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```